# Is it possible to add animations to dgrid rows?

Tags: dojo, css-animations, dgrid

We currently have a dgrid with a single column and rows like this:

[image: dgrid rows]

Recently I added some code so that we can delete rows with the little X button that appears above the row when we hover them.

The handler calls this to delete the row:
this.grid.store.remove(rowId);

When we delete a row, since it's instantaneous and each row contains similar text, it's not always obvious to the user that something just happened.

I was wondering if it would be possible add some sort of dojo or css animation to the row deletion, like the deleted row fading or sliding out. This would make the row deletion more obvious.

Thanks

Comment: you could use a dojo wipeout animation function to slide out the row and then at the end of the animation delete the row. dojo wipeout guide over [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/fx/wipeOut.html#dojo-fx-wipeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frank123/21Lam8wu/) for animating(**wipeOut**) a selected row.

```
require({
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'dgrid',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v0.3.16'
        },
        {
            name: 'xstyle',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/kriszyp/xstyle/v0.2.1'
        },
        {
            name: 'put-selector',
            location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/kriszyp/put-selector/v0.3.5'
        }
    ]
}, [
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
    'dgrid/Selection',
    'dojo/store/Memory',
    "dojo/fx",
    'dojo/domReady!'
], function(declare, Grid, Selection, Memory,fx) {
    var data = [

        { id: 1, name: 'Peter', age:24 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Paul', age: 30 },
         { id: 3, name: 'Mary', age:46 }
    ];
    var store = new Memory({ data: data });
    var options = {
        columns: [
           /*{ field: 'id',  label: 'ID' },*/
            { field: 'name', label: 'Name' },
            { field: 'age', label: 'Age' }

        ],
        store: store
    };
    var CustomGrid = declare([ Grid, Selection ]);
    var grid = new CustomGrid(options, 'gridcontainer');

    grid.on('dgrid-select', function (event) {
    // Report the item from the selected row to the console.
    console.log('Row selected: ', event.rows[0].data);
        //WipeOut animation for selected row.
        fx.wipeOut({ node: event.rows[0].element }).play();

     });

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. Very nice :) I'll still need to make sure to delete the row from the store when the animation is complete, but otherwise this is it.

Comment: To delete the row from the store after the animation is simple, I can use the onEnd property. Like this: fx.wipeOut({ node: query('#myGrid-row-' + rowId)[0], onEnd: lang.hitch(this, function(){ this.grid.store.remove(rowId); }) }).play()

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a event onEnd to which you can attach your delete function for deleting the row.